# What is the default targeted .NET Framework version when i compile an application from Source File?

Tags: c#, frameworks, .net

In the builder application the targeted framework was set to version 4, then i changed it to version 2.0 and suddently i got an error saying :

```
Error   1   No overload for method 'CreateProvider' takes 2 arguments
```

which was occuring on this line of code :

```
provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp", providerOptions);
```

then i simply changed the line above to be :

```
provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
```

Now everything goes OK. But the question is when i don't add the ProviderOptions ( The Dictionary item which holds the compilerversion) Which net framework will be targeted ? v2 or v4 ?

Any help would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

in the 2.0 version of the framework CreateProvider wasn't overloaded to accept providerOptions as you can see in the 2.0 version of the MSDN documentation

[2.0 CreateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

whereas from the 4.0 version onwards the method is overloaded

[4.0 CreateProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

I think in this case the 2.0 framework will be the one used.

Answer (score 1):

Given you are running in v2.0 of the framework, I can't imagine you can target any other version of the runtime.  It's a bit tricky to find confirmation of this, but you can target old frameworks from newer versions of a framework, but you can't do it the other way around. It would destroy the space time continuum i'm sure.

Anyhow, here's the link to the microsoft documentation for CodeDomProvider in 2.0
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yzxs14d.aspx

and another to the referenced GetAllCompilerInfo method, that you might be able to utilise to check out compiler settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.codedomprovider.getallcompilerinfo.aspx